# Makefile for project with code in multiple directories but same directory structure

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following directory structure for a C++ project:

```
.
├── bin
├── build
├── include
│   ├── dir1
│   │   ├── file1.hpp
│   │   └── file2.hpp
│   ├── dir2
│   │   ├── file3.hpp
│   │   └── file4.hpp
│   └── third_party
│       └── catch.hpp
├── Makefile
├── src
│   ├── dir1
│   │   ├── file1.cpp
│   │   └── file2.cpp
│   └── dir2
│       ├── file3.cpp
│       └── file4.cpp
└── test
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── file1.test.cpp
    │   └── file2.test.cpp
    └── dir2
        ├── file3.test.cpp
        └── file4.test.cpp
```

How can I write the Makefile to compile the code in `src` and `test` directories and obtain the object files in the `build` directory and the binaries in the `bin` directory, maintaining the same directory structure within them, **without having to name every file and its dependency explicitly**? Would it be better to use multiple Makefiles in each `dir*` within `src` and `test`?

My Makefile currently looks like this: (it's probably nonsensical, sorry about that!)

```
binaries_dir = bin
build_dir = build
sources_dir = src
include_dir = include

compile_flags = -std=c++14 -Wall

binaries := $(wildcard *.out)
objects := $(wildcard *.o)
sources := $(wildcard *.cpp)
headers := $(wildcard *.hpp)

objects: $(sources)
    g++ $(compile_flags) -c $(sources_dir)/$(sources) -I $(include_dir)

binaries: $(objects)
    for object in $(objects); do
        g++ $(compile_flags) -o $(binaries_dir)/ $(build_dir)/$object
    done
```

Comment: I've got an (incomplete) couple of articles here https://latedev.wordpress.com/2014/11/08/generic-makefiles-with-gcc-and-gnu-make/ on how to write  a generic makefile, which may or may not be useful.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This seems useful, thanks! Going through it ATM.

Comment: It really depends on what your target *program(s)* is/are. Does this all build one program? Or one program per source file?

Comment: @Galik One program per source file

Comment: Presumable then the file names will be unique so that in the `bin` dir the programs don't overwrite each other? Or do you want the same subdirectories under the `bin` dir you have in the source directories?

Comment: @Galik I would like the same structure to be maintained under both `bin` and `build`. For example, I should get the executables `bin/dir1/file1` and `bin/dir1/file1.test` from the source and test code of `file1` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is fool proof but I think it pretty much does what you are after. You should study up on building Makefiles because it this turns out not to quite fit your needs, how are you going to fix it?

```bash
CXX := g++
RM  := rm -f
MD  := mkdir -p

# don't change, this is for dependencies
CXXFLAGS += -MMD -MP

# add compiler flags here
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14 -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra
CXXFLAGS += -g3 -O0

# add external includes here
CPPFLAGS += -Iinclude

# add library flags here
LDFLAGS +=

DIRS := $(patsubst  src/%, %, $(wildcard  src/*))
DIRS += $(patsubst test/%, %, $(wildcard test/*))
PROG_SOURCES := $(wildcard  src/*/*.cpp)
TEST_SOURCES := $(wildcard test/*/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst  src/%.cpp, build/%.o, $(PROG_SOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst test/%.cpp, build/%.o, $(TEST_SOURCES))
EXECUTABLES := $(patsubst  src/%.cpp, bin/%, $(PROG_SOURCES))
EXECUTABLES += $(patsubst test/%.cpp, bin/%, $(TEST_SOURCES))
DEPENDENCIES := $(patsubst   src/%.cpp, build/%.d, $(PROG_SOURCES)) 
DEPENDENCIES += $(patsubst  test/%.cpp, build/%.d, $(TEST_SOURCES)) 

all: dirs $(EXECUTABLES)

build/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

build/%.o: test/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

bin/%: build/%.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

-include $(DEPENDENCIES)

clean:
    @echo Removing build files
    @$(RM) $(EXECUTABLES) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDENCIES)

dirs:
    @$(MD) $(patsubst %, build/%, $(DIRS)) $(patsubst %, bin/%, $(DIRS))

.PHONY: show dirs
```

Comment: Will definitely read the manual in depth for more on Makefiles. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might find some inspiration from this: https://github.com/jschmerge/DasBuild

Comment: Will take a look at this too. Thanks!